# Restart Id=1 when deleting every record in a table? (Angular + Spring Boot + MySQL)

Tags: javascript, mysql, angular, spring, spring-boot

I'm developing a simple CRUD application using Angular for the Frontend part, Spring Boot for the Backend and MySQL for the Database.

I've managed to insert, retrieve and Update/Delete the values inside my table, but I'm struggling with restarting the value of the Id (which I set as Primary Key) when I delete all the records from my CRUD table. I mean, if I have 10 records (Id = 1,...,10) and I delete all of them, the next first insert will have Id=1 and I would like it to be equal to 1. I'm using InnoDB as the engine.

Frontend part -

.html file

```
  <button class="m-3 btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="removeAllRecords()">
    Remove All
  </button>
```

.ts file

```
  removeAllRecords(): void {
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ALL your records?")){
this.recordService.deleteAll()
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.refreshList();
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

service.ts file

```
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/records';

deleteAll(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.delete(baseUrl);
}
```

Backend part - I'm using on Spring Boot the Datajpa repository:

model file

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "crud")
public class Record{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
....
}
```

controller file

```
@DeleteMapping("/records")
public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deleteAllRecords() {
    try {
        contactRepository.deleteAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

Now, I think something must be done in the above function or something on the definition of the table, but I'm not understand what and how...can you please help me?

P.S. I'm using using these settings in the application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/codejavadb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= *pwd*
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

hope I made myself clear, I'm quite new with all these kinds of tools and syntaxes, any help would be really appreciated, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add a logic to set primary key. before making any insert, check the counts of records. If there are records, next primary key will be +1. If there is no record, it will return 0 so +1 will assign primary key as 1 to that insertion.

Comment: In what part I would add this logic? In the function I defined in Spring Boot? Anyway, isn't the logic already in "@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)"?